Единственное или множественное число слова "кредо"
Как правильно:

Главное кредо Андрея – саморазвитие, открытость, честность.

или

Главные кредо Андрея – саморазвитие, открытость, честность.


Что такое "кредо"?

основа мировоззрения человека

Пишут, что:

КРЕДО (от латинского credo - верую), 1) в католической церкви символ
веры. 2) Убеждения, взгляды, основы мировоззрения (например,
политическое кредо, научное кредо).

То есть "верую (в) саморазвитие, открытость, честность...."
Видимо из-за того, что это глагол, форма множественного числа вряд ли нужна. Либо это "символ веры", а символ веры может включать несколько связанных по смыслу положений. Или по другому кредо - это главное убеждение.
Однако, давать перечисление ряда понятий, не совсем мне кажется верным, лучше сделать так:
Кредо Андрея: "саморазвитие, открытость, честность."

Он начинает свою речь фразой, отражающей его рабочее кредо: «Не нужно
знать многое, нужно знать нужное!» Г. Аврех. Исследователь на перепутье // «Химия и жизнь», 1968.

Но так как кредо - это главное убеждение или основа веры, тогда слово "главное" - это плеоназм.
Либо вообще заменить слово "кредо", на "девиз", потому что перечисление понятий больше походит на "девиз". "Главный девиз", наверное, не плеоназм.

ДЕВИ́З, девиза, муж. (франц. devise).

Краткое изречение, выражающее руководящую идею поведения или деятельности. Девиз пионеров "Всегда готов". || Краткое изречение,
которое ставит автор на проекте вместо своего имени на анонимных
конкурсах. Первую премию получил проект под девизом "Вперед".
В геральдике - краткая надпись на гербе или щите (спец.). Ушаков.


Главный девиз Андрея: "Саморазвитие, открытость, честность!"
Ну или если уж кредо, то нужно расширить:
Кредо Андрея: "В жизни человека самое важное - постоянное саморазвитие, открытость к людям, и честность перед самим собой."
